# How to get only Hashtag feeds

Tags: node.js, hashtag, feed

I am creating an app with Node.js express to display social media feeds. I want to filter social media feeds from API using HASHTAGS.

i.e. Facebook is providing hashtags in feeds, Like (#Cricket). I want only that feeds from Facebook API, which has only #Cricket tags.

Is this possible to get filtered feeds from any social networking site.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter tweets by hashtags. It's actually really easy to do and the Twitter API documentation is pretty solid. I recommend to start looking here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Facebook used to provide a hashtag search, but it is now deprecated. As reported here: http://wersm.com/facebook-is-deprecating-its-hashtag-search-api/ and in various other places if you search for it.